# If $\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right |\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n} \; \; \forall r>0$, then $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The title is what I want to show to solve this problem which includes two mini parts.

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. Suppose that there exist $C\in \mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ s.t for all $r>0$ we have $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left | f(r\exp(it)) \right |\text{d}t \leq Cr^\beta .$$

In the first mini part of this problem, I had to show that for every $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and every $r>0$ we have that $$\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right | \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}.$$

The second part I'm working on now asks us to show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

("Please, assume that you have already proven $\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right | \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}.$")

To do the second part, I thought the Identity Theorem would be applicable, so I wanted to show that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ first.

Since, $\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right | \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}$ for all $r>0$,
I thought $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right |\leq \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}=0$ must be true so that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

However, the solution did this in another way.

It first made two cases "i: $\beta >n$, ii: $\beta <n$."

And, showed that

i: if $\beta >n$, then $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right |\leq \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}=0$.

ii: if $\beta <n$, then $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\left | f^{(n)}(0) \right |\leq \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{2\pi}Cr^{\beta -n}=0$.

i,ii shows that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

But, I don't understand the solution and don't think it is necessary to do casework.

I would like to know if my approach is wrong, why it is wrong, and moreover, why the solution did the casework.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that you're taking limot over $r$, so the limit of $r^{\beta-n}$ depends on the sign of $\beta-n$.

So if $\beta>n$, then $\beta-n>0$ and $\lim_{r\to0}r^{\beta-n}=0$.

If $\beta<n$, then $n-\beta>0$ and $\lim_{r\to0}r^{\beta-n}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{r^{n-\beta}}=\infty$ and the argument fails. BUT in this case, you can take limit when $r\to\infty$, sinc if $n-\beta>0$, then $\lim_{r\to\infty}r^{n-\beta}=\infty$ and we have that $$\lim_{r\to0}r^{\beta-n}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{r^{n-\beta}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0,$$ and the arguments cames useful again.

Comment: Ah! I missed the easy part. Thanks a lot!